# migrating from Windows: will mozyhome and itunes be accessible?

Tags: backup, restore, itunes

I am thinking of buying a new laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed.
I have backed up everything from my current comuter to the cloud using MozyHome.
I would like to know

1. will downloading all my files again onto my new Ubuntu machine work?
2. will I somehow be able to play all of the iTunes music files which I
   have backed up?

I don't want to have to reinstall iTunes, or any other of the bloated corporate software I am trying to get away from with this (possible) switch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to AskUbuntu and StackExchange!

From a glance at the [Mozy download page](http://mozy.co.uk/home/download/), they don't offer a Linux client, so you may have difficulties there. A good alternative is [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/), who give you 2GB space for free and supports Mac, Linux and Windows.

iTunes is also Windows/Mac only, but the good news is that (unprotected) iTunes music files are compatible with [any number of Ubuntu's media players](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/list-of-media-players-to-install-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/); though if you have any tracks with DRM, you may not be able to play them.

My advice would be to create MP3 copies of all your tracks before moving to Ubuntu - see [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1550).

Comment: Note in addition: I can confirm that non DRM-protected .m4a files from an iTunes library will play without issue on most music players once the codecs are installed. Converting the m4a files to mp3 however inevitably led to quite an audible drop in quality on my system, I cant recommend this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  Have now been in touch with Mozy & although they don't have a Linux client, you can back up your files from their website, so I am in business.  Excellent.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Takkat - Slightly off-topic, but I'm unsure how converting to MP3 would lead to loss. If you use the correct bitrate (i.e. the same or higher), you shouldn't lose anything noticeable - if you convert a track and it sounds audibly awful, you should check your MP3 encoding settings (I always go with 320kbps MP3, with the reasoning that although you can't replace loss - M4A is still a "lossy" format - you can do your best not to increase it).