# Do keyboard shortcuts used in Windows work in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

As I mentioned [in another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319966/migrating-from-windows-will-mozyhome-and-itunes-be-accessible), I am thinking of buying a new laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed.

I share a laptop with my partner who knows much less about computers than me.
Since the lessons I have given my partner on shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> &  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>  to copy & paste have really 'stuck', I would like to know if these will still work.

I am still trying to decide if switching is right thing to do - we are going to try Ubuntu on current laptop first, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+X`, `Ctrl+V` is working right out of the box when installing Ubuntu. The majority of the other shortcuts such as Windows `WinKey+E` (open file browser), `WinKey+D` (show desktop) and other can be setup in several ways, of which I suggest the usage of Compiz Config Settings Manager in which you'll find the "Commands" Plugin, inside of which you can define your desired commands and their respective key bindings.

Several other useful tools and system configurations can be reached on this site by running a search.

If you have need to define a more specific key bindings to certain task don't hesitate to let us know.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. :) BTW

Good luck!

*P.S. Compiz Config Settings Manager must be installed in order to be used. This can be easily installed via the Ubuntu Software Center.*

Comment: +1 a fine answer but I'd caution against dragging someone into `ccsm` who doesn't need to be there as you can wedge a configuration too easily with that tool. Most Windows users that I've ever asked about it have no idea that the WinKey does anything at all (except maybe open Start).

Comment: Thak you. I agree that many people have just noticed the existence of the WinKey but the usage of WinKey in Ubuntu is really useful as you can define almost any key bindings to fit your needs. Newcomers to Ubuntu should take in consideration that the existence of powerful tools as CCSM requires knowledge and learning before using. And my inclusion on the answer obeys to the need to let the asker know that there are many other key bindings than those mentioned in the question. Thank you for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many default common shortcuts with Windows for most Desktop Environments, so ctrl-c & ctrl-v should work by default almost everywhere, but more important is, you can most often reconfigure shortcuts if they don't fit your style. I don't suppose there should be any major problem with that.